# Hibernate to swapfile on encrypted volume

Tags: hibernate, luks

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on LUKS encrypted partition that is on the mdadm raid-0.

I want to activate suspend to disk. I used [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946) instruction (for unencrypted partition), but it doesn't work. Computer shutdowns but doesn't resume, it starts as after hard reboot.

Can I setup hibernation on my configuration? If it is possible how can I do it?

Comment: When you did the step `echo "resume=UUID=<your UUID> resume_offset=<youroffset>" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, what exactly did you run (i.e., what did you fill in the blanks with)?

Comment: <your UUID> - uuid of root partition (or I tried resume=/dev/mapper/<root_partition> too)
 <youroffset> - output of swap-offset /swapfile

Answer (score 2):

I did a lot of testing regarding this, and I found out the issue isn't actually related to encryption. The real reason that it isn't working is solely because you're using a swap file instead of a swap partition. Note the following at the end of `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/resume`:

```
SWAPTYPE=$(wait-for-root "${resume}" ${RESUMEDELAY:-5})

case "${SWAPTYPE}" in
    swsuspend|s1suspend|s2suspend|ulsuspend|tuxonice)
        if [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && plymouth --ping; then
                plymouth message --text="Resuming from $resume"
        fi

        # hardcode path, uswsusp ships an resume binary too
        if [ -n "${resume_offset}" ]; then
                /bin/resume ${resume} ${resume_offset}
        else
                /bin/resume ${resume}
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Here, `${resume}` and `${resume_offset}` have the values that you put in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. When it calls `wait-for-root`, it's looking at the partition type of `${resume}`, which isn't swap (it's ext4 or whatever type your root partition is). It then compares this to its list of suspended swap types, and (unsurprisingly) doesn't find a match, so it doesn't resume. It looks like they intend for swap files to work since they use `${resume_offset}` at all, so this appears to be a bug in Ubuntu's initramfs-tools system. (Edit: This is apparently a known issue, as mentioned on [their SwapFaq wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).)

As a workaround, you can avoid the need to have a swap file by using LVM on top of your encrypted partition and then putting a swap partition inside of it along with your root partition, which will work fine with no special steps required.

Comment: I have already installed OS, and shrinking partitions in my configuration is so hard. Is there a solution without modifying partition table?

Comment: As I know it should work with swapfile on unencrypted partition.

Comment: I tried it myself with an unencrypted swap file and it didn't work, for the same reason.

Comment: In fact, hibernation to a swap file on an encrypted volume works just fine on Ubuntu, even with swsusp. The only things stopping it from resuming is the piece of code you found - the FAQ is incorrect claiming that swsusp won't work with swap files. There is already a [bug report on this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1644975), without real activity unfortunately.